# Error on performSegue to UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to `performSegue()` with an animation from left:

```
class SegueFromLeft: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let src = self.source
        let dst = self.destination

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: .curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        },
                       completion: { finished in
                        src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
        )
    }
```

But somehow I get the following error for this line: `src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)`, when `performSegue` is being executed:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16b607fc0)

I can see the animation, but as soon as the new view is being displayed - the app crashes.

PageViewController in case it helps:

```
class LeasingTutorialViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource  {

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "leasingPageOne")
        let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "leasingPageTwo")

        return [vc1, vc2]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first as? LeasingPageOneViewController {
            self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else { return nil }

        return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1

        guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else { return nil }

        return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
    }
}
```

Edit:

It's called in a different ViewController ("goToLeasingTutorial") under some conditions:

Another important note: As soon as I restart the app, it works fine again.

```
@IBAction func goToLeasing(_ sender: Any) {
        if leasingTutorialSeen == false && leasingInStartScreen == true {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLeasingTutorial", sender: self)
        } else if leasingTutorialSeen == true && leasingInStartScreen == true {
            buttonHamburgerTapped(self)

            let parentVC = self.parent as! RootPageViewController
            parentVC.setViewControllers([parentVC.viewControllerList[1]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if leasingTutorialSeen == true && leasingInStartScreen == false {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLeasing", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you're doing appears to be an attempt to write a custom segue that does a presentation but with a custom animation. Is that right? If so, that's not how you do it. You must call `super` and use a custom transition animation.

Comment: Another question I have for you is what this has to do with the page view controller. You cannot customize anything about the animation within a page view controller. You say "when `performSegue` is called, but I never see you calling it, so it's unclear what you're trying to do in the first place.

Comment: @matt I added the code it's being called in to the initial question.

Comment: But why did you show the page view controller? How is that relevant? I don't get it.

Comment: Also please never write `if leasingTutorialSeen == false && leasingInStartScreen == true`. Don't compare things to `true` and `false`. Write `if !leasingTutorialSeen && leasingInStartScreen`.

Comment: I really don't understand the segue at all. I don't know where it is triggered (which one of those identifiers is this segue?). I don't understand how you can do a segue that presents its _source_ — the idea of a segue is the _destination_ appears. I ask you again, what is this segue supposed to do?

Comment: @Matt It's `goToLeasingTutorial` - it's supposed to show the PageViewController and the ViewController it contains, coming from the left.

Comment: So what is the `present` at the end for?

Comment: I don't care where you got it. What you're doing is wrong. There is a correct way to do a _custom transition animation_ and what you're doing is not it. — You say you want to have the view controller come in from the left. But what kind of view controller parentage are we to have? Is this, as I have guessed, supposed to be a modal / presentation segue?

Comment: If so, here's a downloadable example you can adapt to your own purposes: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p325customSegue/CustomSegue/ViewController.swift

Comment: @matt Thanks! I'm new to Swift and haven't figured out the whole Segue thing yet. Anyways, I'll try to implement the example given by you and come back to you later.

Comment: It has nothing to do with _Swift_. This is about programming iOS (Cocoa). Language is irrelevant.

Comment: @matt I haven't had a lot of experience with iOS either. Swift is the first time that I interact with apps. Anyways, it works fine now, thank's a lot! - Would you be so nice as to explain the difference between my initial version and yours a little more? I didn't really get the problem.